# Can a workflow step access environment variables provided by an EnvironmentContributingAction?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

A custom plugin we wrote for an older version of Jenkins uses an EnvironmentContributingAction to provide environment variables to the execution so they could be used in future build steps and passed as parameters to downstream jobs.

While attempting to convert our build to workflow, I'm having trouble accessing these variables:

```
node {
    // this step queries an API and puts the results in
    // environment variables called FE1|BE1_INTERNAL_ADDRESS
    step([$class: 'SomeClass', parameter: foo])

    // this ends up echoing 'null and null'
    echo "${env.FE1_INTERNAL_ADDRESS} and ${env.BE1_INTERNAL_ADDRESS}"
}
```

Is there a way to access the environment variable that was injected?  Do I have to convert this functionality to a build wrapper instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnvironmentContributingAction` is currently limited to `AbstractBuild`s, which `WorkflowRun`s are not, so pending [JENKINS-29537](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29537) which I just filed, your plugin would need to be modified somehow. Options include:

- Have the builder add a plain `Action` instead, then register an `EnvironmentContributor` whose `buildEnvironmentFor(Run, …)` checks for its presence using `Run.getAction(Class)`.
- Switch to a `SimpleBuildWrapper` which defines the environment variables within a scope, then invoke it from Workflow using the `wrap` step.
- Depend on `workflow-step-api` and define a custom Workflow `Step` with comparable functionality but directly returning a `List<String>` or whatever makes sense in your context. ([code sample](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/7adacf00e752fedb1c512f4e2716dbb5e56e5a7c/basic-steps/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/ReadFileStep.java#L83-90))

Answer (score 0):

Since [PR-2975](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/2975) is merged, you are able to use new interface:
`void buildEnvVars(@Nonnull Run<?, ?> run, @Nonnull EnvVars env, @CheckForNull Node node)`

It will be used by old type of builds as well.

Comment: I have a follow-up PR amending the signature to `buildEnvironment(Run, EnvVars)`.